# Am I risking damaging this LED backlight?

Tags: led

I have a 12 key matrix keypad with an LED backlight that I am wiring up with an Arduino. The datasheet for it is here;

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1359150.pdf

It states pretty clearly that the LED has Vmax = 4V and Vnom = 3.5V. I take this to mean that I should power the LED with 3.5V and never more than 4V. Is this correct?

The Arduino puts out 5V and I am able to use a resistor to drop the voltage to about 3.2V (measured with a multimeter). The problem with this is that the backlight seems fairly dim at that voltage. If I power it directly with 5V (for short periods of time) the backlight seems nice and bright and how I would like it to be. If I leave it like this will it eventually damage the LED? I plan to get some more resistors to try to get a voltage closer to 4V but I don't have any to hand just yet.

Comment: you could replace the resistor with two diodes .... these would drop the voltage by 1.2V  or so

Comment: How are you measuring the drop? Is that 3.2V across the resistor?

Comment: I like the diodes suggested by @jsotola it's a no brainer and will not vary with current fluctuation .  You can do it with a resistor,   The current = (5v-3.2V) / R.  New R = 1.5V/ (1.8/ R).

Comment: @Passerby no, that would be 1.8V (5V-3.2V) across the resistor.

Comment: @Misunderstood You are not op and you have no way of knowing how op measured it.

Comment: the datasheet says 5V is too much. use a lower resistance to get the LED voltage closer to 3.6V

Comment: it's a pity that the datasheet doesn't say how much current the LED wants.

Comment: It's 3.2V across the LED.

Answer (score 2):

the best way is to drive that LED not directly from Arduino pin (because you may sink or source overrated current from the pin and damage the pin) but using a simple transistor switch like below schematic  [image: transistor switch]

Comment: OK. That's very helpful. Thanks. I have a PN2222 transistor lying around. I believe that's basically the same thing. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't yet understand how that can damage a pin, but I'm happy to take advice that it can. I've tried implementing your circuit and it works, but the LED is even dimmer. I now measure a voltage of 2.5V across the LED without the 220 ohm resistor!

Comment: Actually, further testing. My arduino only puts out 3.3V on the output pins. I must have been measuring this initially. I've implemented your circuit above without the 220 ohm resistor and have dropped the 100kohm resistor down to just 1kohm. If I measure the voltage across the LED pins on the keypad I measure 3.2V and it seems bright enough. Does this seem suitable/safe?

Comment: The 220ohm resistor is important.

Answer (score 1):

The backlight circuit is likely just some combination of LEDs with **no** series resistor. You can damage them by putting 5V on them directly.

You should use a series resistor to drop your power supply voltage to the LED voltage. They state that the voltage will be 3.5V nominally and no more than 4V, but do not state the operating current (terrible datasheet). If we **assume** 15mA then the resistor would be (5-3.5)/0.015 = 100 ohms. If the LED voltage was 4V you would only get 10mA of current, which would be a bit dimmer.

Another alternative would be some kind of constant current circuit but that's unnecessarily complicated.